# css3 opacity google site

Tags: css, opacity, sites

i try to make a container for my site in google site that will be transparent so that the 
background image will be visible.

i guess opacity property of css3 is not supported by google sites,
so is there any other way to do that? thanx
i tried

> filter: alpha (opacity=50); -moz-opacity: 0.50; opacity: 0.50; -khtml-opacity: 0.5; but it's not recognized.
>
> WARNING: Your HTML contains some tags that are not permitted. These have been removed from your changes.

Comment: Why downvoting this? They guy asked a perfectly ok question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it allows you you can do that by applying a semi-transparent 1px x 1px .png image to the background of your container.

```
.yourContainer {
background:transparent url(myTransparentImage.png) repeat;
}
```